# Windows 10 Start menu wrong icon

Tags: windows-10

I have 2 apps installed: Mozilla Firefox and Tor Browser.

Tor Browser is a Firefox based browser and has the same name of its executable: firefox.exe.

The problem is that the Start menu started to show me the same icons for both apps and I don't know how to fix this.

It worked fine for a while, but got broken for an unknown reason.

Tor app (firefox.exe) and Firefox browser (firefox.exe) definitely has different icons. But....

[image]

[image]

Comment: Two possible ways, try to rebuild icon cache in Windows explorer. Or delete the shortcut of Tor browser in Start Menu folder and replace it with a new one.

Comment: How to rebuild the cache? Removing shortcut and creating a new one pointing to a different location did not help.

Comment: See this [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/232779/how-to-rebuild-a-broken-icon-cache-in-windows-10/).

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help either.

Comment: Some relevant information from the Chrome team (who are dealing with the same problem with their `.lnk` files for Chrome Apps) can be found [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=571230#c25).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The icon and the background of the start menu tile is determined by the "`.VisualElementsManifest.xml`" file. Tor Browser uses the wrong icon because Tor uses the same manifest as Firefox.

To fix it, go to your Tor directory, where `firefox.exe` (Tor Browser) is placed. There you should find "`firefox.VisualElementsManifest.xml`". (You can see that the logos linked in the file are of Firefox.) You can simply delete it, or rename it to something like "`firefox.VisualElementsManifest_.xml`". Without the manifest file, the tile will use the default background color and a small icon of the program. Alternatively, you can modify the manifest file and the image files it directs to, to choose a custom background color and icon.

This doesn't solve it immediately, as the tile info is cached. You can try removing the tile, renaming the shortcut in the start menu and then readding the tile, but I have found that it doesn't always work. [Instead, use the method described here](https://www.askvg.com/tip-customize-start-screen-tiles-background-color-text-color-and-logo-in-windows-8-1/) to reload the cache, by executing the following in Powershell:

```
(ls "$env:appdata\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\Tor Browser.lnk").lastwritetime = get-date
```

Change the shortcut name if yours is different, or if it is in programdata instead of appdata. After that, readd the tile.

Comment: NICE ANSWER !  Please keep it up, our site grows from the contributions of members like you!

Comment: New link is "Start Tor Browser.lnk" now